# Every update fails

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using VSCode for months and enjoying it for Python. Every update done through the app (by clicking the "Update" button on bottom right popup) has resulted in a failure to close VSCode. I find it odd because the only executable VSCode.exe running in process is the installer. If I kill that process I kill the installation. Either way, it jacks up my VSCode installation and I have to re-download it from Microsoft. This happens on both my Windows 10 devices.

Is there another way to update VSCode where this is not an issue?

Comment: Tried reinstalling?

Comment: Yes, that would work. So are you saying the answer is every time there is an update from VSCode I should download the complete installation from Microsoft? I understand that is my way to restore the application I am looking for an alternate update experience.

Comment: No, I'm saying that your install is broke somehow, likely. And reinstalling is often the only way to fix a broke install. I can guarantee this is not normal behavior.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, the last several updates have required a full install as the update always fails saying it can't gain access to a file.  The reinstalls also fail, but I can ignore the file (which doesn't exist) and get it installed.